# Помогите понять и изменить код JS для плавной прокрутки по якорям на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css

Этот код взят с интернета и работает, но как мне например просто оставить только кнопку Up изменив JS код и как он вообще работает, что за что отвечает? А если я удаляю
`? $('#down') : $('#up')`
то тогда прокрутка становится не плавная а резкая

```js
$('#up, #down').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var target= $(this).get(0).id == "up" ? $('#down') : $('#up');
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
       scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.up {
    width:100px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: #22222290;
}

.down {
    width:100px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #22222250;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="up" href="#down">down</a>
<div class="up"></div>

<a id="down" href="#up">up</a>
<div class="down"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#up').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.up {
  width: 100px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #22222290;
}

.down {
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #22222250;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="up"></div>
<a id="up" href="#">up</a>
<div class="down"></div>
```